# Cannot run .py files from command line, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Something'

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface

You can run *.py* files in Pycharm, but you cannot run the same file from CLI?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because one of the modules you try to import is not installed in your environment. I would recommend installing an environment management tool like anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). Then create a new environment, activate it and run:

pip install Something